# Как удалять элементы в xml?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

У меня есть файл xml вот с таким содержанием

```
<shop>
     <categories>
        <category id="132">Детское</category>
        <category id="62" parentId="133">Женские</category>
        <category id="172" parentId="1">Мужское</category>
    </categories>

    <materials>
        <material id="1">хлопок</material>
        <material id="2">вискоза</material>
        <material id="3">эластан</material>
    </materials>

    <offers>

            <offer id="41850" available="true">
                <price>3220</price>
                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
                <date>2015-02-05</date>
            </offer>
            <offer id="41850" available="true">
                <price>3220</price>
                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
                <date>2015-02-05</date>
            </offer>
            <offer id="41850" available="true">
                <price>3220</price>
                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
                <date>2015-02-05</date>
            </offer>
        <offer id="77777" available="true">
                <price>3250</price>
                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
                <date>2015-02-05</date>
            </offer>
        <offer id="41340" available="true">
                <price>3120</price>
                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
                <date>2015-02-05</date>
            </offer>
```

Мне необходимо убрать `categories` и `materials`, потом необходимо выбрать только уникальные `offer` и записать в xml. На каждом `offer` я делаю действие.

Проблема в том, что не пойму как удалить `offer` по его `id`, в xml записывает удалив `category` и `materials`. =(
Вот мой код.

```
    $url = 'test.xml';
$yml = simplexml_load_file($url);  //Интерпретирует XML-файл в объект
unset($yml->shop->categories);     //удаляем категории
unset($yml->shop->materials);      //удаляем материалы

$itemid = '0'; //id предыдущего массива

foreach ($yml->shop->offers->offer as $item){
    $sravnit = $item['id'];  //пишем id проходимого offer
    if("$sravnit" == "$itemid") {
        echo "$sravnit равен $itemid - удаляем товар<br>";
        unset($yml->shop->offers->offer[$sravnit]); //удаляем
        continue; 
    else {echo "$sravnit Не равен $itemid ";
    $itemid = $sravnit;
    echo "itemid присвоен номер - $itemid <br>"; 
    }


 }
$yml->asXML('odd.xml');
```

Comment: Может быть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array) посмотрите работу с массивами?

Comment: Так я также делаю, разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

как то так наверное.

```
$url = 'test.xml';
$yml = simplexml_load_file($url);  //Интерпретирует XML-файл в объект
unset($yml->shop->categories);     //удаляем категории
unset($yml->shop->materials);      //удаляем материалы

$itemid = '0'; //id предыдущего массива
$i = 0;
foreach ($yml->shop->offers->offer as $item) {
    $sravnit = $item['id'];  //пишем id проходимого offer
    if ("$sravnit" == "$itemid") {
        echo "$sravnit равен $itemid - удаляем товар<br>";
        unset($yml->shop->offers[$i]); //удаляем
        continue; else {
            echo "$sravnit Не равен $itemid ";
            $itemid = $sravnit;
            echo "itemid присвоен номер - $itemid <br>";
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
$yml->asXML('odd.xml');
```

Comment: Неа, это не будет работать. Я так уже делал. Ваш код загрузил, подправил ошибки но тоже не заработало.